# button icon not showing at android toolbar

Tags: android

i have problem with my android code. i want to create button icon at android toolbar. and the icon is showing at preview. see my picture below
[menu.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxvKt.png)

but when i run this project, the button icon is not showing up. 
[run project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyzLe.png)

and this is my activity code

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout dr;
private Toolbar toolbar;

private View navHeader;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    dr = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    dr.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    selectDrawerItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

whats the problem ? any suggestion would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: add your styles to the question please thanks :)

Comment: Add the `R.menu.menu` file to the question.

Comment: have you used r.menu...

Comment: i am sorry everyone. i've updated my question. check please:)

Comment: Why are you using mipmaps instead of drawables for the icons?

Answer (score 0):

create a resource file in menu named it main_menu_tool.xml & paste bellow code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:balloonberry="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <item
   android:id="@+id/miCompose"
   balloonberry:showAsAction="always"
   android:icon="@drawable/menu"/>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/miProfile"
   balloonberry:showAsAction="always"
   android:icon="@drawable/week_view"/>

</menu>
```

In Main2Activity just write like ...

```
    @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_tool, menu);
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: i got something. when i change the icon to be android widget such button, spinner, etc. it's working. but if i use my drawable icon, its  not working. have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code of Menu.XML I wrote for a location icon. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Wk1.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/Location1"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/location"
    android:title="@string/location"

    />
</menu>
```

And part of MainActivity.java representing the icon

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.Location1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Location.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope it helps.